# How to find the width of a form as a percentage of the client window in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

Following is my page in which i am creating a table. I want to know my page size, width and height in percentages. Please help me.

```
<script>    
    alert(document.body.clientWidth);   
    document.getElementById('form1').offsetWidth;
</script> 
<body> 
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="pbl mbl">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="list">

        </table>
        <div class="pagination pagination-right" id="pager"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks but what is that #someElt?? is that form id?

Comment: assume in you case it's table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the percentage of the entire client window (as opposed to the percentage of the `offsetParent()` as in the linked thread) you could use a similar technique, just divide by the `document.body.clientWidth` instead of the `offsetParent().width()`.

*In vanilla Javascript:*

```
var client = document.body.clientWidth;
var form = document.getElementById('form1').clientWidth;
alert(((form/client)*100)+'%');
```

Alternatively, if you're after the size of the client window as a percentage of the available screen resolution, you can add this to the above and note the second alert:

```
var screen = window.screen.availWidth;
alert(((client/screen)*100)+'%');
```